# How to not lock two files with Assembly.Load

Tags: c#

If I copy a file

```
File.Copy(src, dst);
```

and then load the copy

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(dst);
```

**Why are *both* files locked by my process?**

If I delete the src before I load the dst, and then recopy the dst back to the src I get my desired end result. But the delete and copy seem a little unnecessary.

```
File.Copy(src, dst);
File.Delete(src);
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dst);
File.Copy(dst, src);
```

Yes I am building a plugin-design application. Yes I could be using AppDomains with Shadow Copy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx). Yes I will have to manage my own type cache (as each assembly load will give a different type as far as my AppDomain is concerned). But these are not answers to my question.

Note that src and dst are strings. No other stream is opened on the files.

Comment: I edited my comment but now it has nothing to do with your original problem I will mark my answer as well for Delete.. thanks Payo

Comment: The simple explanation is that *src* is already loaded by your process, a rather common mishap with plugins.  Then again, if it is really locked then deleting it can't work.  So maybe it isn't locked.

Comment: haha, "it is but it isn't"? :) The src just after copy is still not locked (verified manually and with external tools checking the file locks). The src file locks when Assembly.Load is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the source file is in the assembly resolution path for your application, and so it is loaded automatically.  Try making src `C:\Temp` or some other path that has nothing to do with your application's folder, and see if the same thing occurs.

Comment: The path was in fact the same. I have taken your advice and found more confusing and non-repeating behavior; it worked to move it but the load fails some of the time now when left in the app's folder. I am currently trying to pinpoint a reproducible issue with the code. (This could be the answer, let me troubleshoot)

Comment: It appears LoadFrom doesn't lock both, only LoadFile. Updating question. Also, taking the file out of the application's own dir DOES keep it from being locked. Note, however, the lock still doesn't occur until Assembly.LoadFile - not on application start. I'm still giving you the answer as the solution was to move the files to another folder.